# Ruby on Rails i18n breadcumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale, breadcrumbs

I'm using default Rails i18n and have got a problem with i18ing breadcrumbs. I use gem called "breadcrumbs_on_rails" to render breadcrumbs, so I add breadcrumbs-links in controllers like this:

```
add_breadcrumb I18n.t('interface.home'), :root_path
```

The problem is, that controller doesn't seem to know about current locale and always uses default language.

How do I tell i18n to use selected locale, not default?

**UPDATE:**
Controllers know about current locale. But problem appears in strange circumstances. I used the same code in two different places in one method and found out, that i18n does not work on line **6** and works on line **10** of the following example code:

```
def index
  @device = Device.find_by_id(params[:device_id])
  if @device != nil
    if current_user?(User.find(@device))
      logger.debug I18n.locale # Outputs en - wrong
      add_breadcrumb t('interface.all_events'), device_events_path(@device) # Does not work
      logger.debug I18n.locale # Outputs de - correct
      add_breadcrumb @device.title, device_path(@device)
      logger.debug I18n.locale # Outputs de - correct
      add_breadcrumb t('interface.all_events'), device_events_path(@device) # Works perfect
      @events = @device.events.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
    else
      redirect_to :root
    end
  else
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

Locale is set in application_controller.rb like was adviced in tutorial, but using http_accept_language for detection:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  def default_url_options(options={})
    I18n.locale = get_accepted_language
    { :locale => get_accepted_language }
  end

  def get_accepted_language
    available_locales = %w{en de}
    request.user_preferred_languages
    request.preferred_language_from(available_locales)
  end
end
```

URLs look like this: `http://localhost:3000/de/devices/3/events`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get and set the current locale:

```
I18n.locale
```

Get default locale:

```
I18n.default_locale
```

Here is all you need:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

---

Try to use approach from official guides. You can set locale using `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    I18n.locale = get_accepted_language
    { :locale => get_accepted_language }
  end

  def get_accepted_language
    available_locales = %w{en de}
    request.user_preferred_languages
    request.preferred_language_from(available_locales)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've already set locale in application_controller. There is no problems with I18n.t in views, only in controllers.
I've discovered new details, watch question updates in a minute.

Comment: Sure, tested once again right now: works at line 7 and doesn't work at line 5 even with I18n.t

Comment: Looks weird. Try to put flags `p I18n.locale` before line 5 and 7, to debug and get what is current locale at that point.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Output is fun: en (wrong) before line 5, de (correct) between lines 5 and 6, de (correct) bewtween lines 6 and 7.

Comment: Updated question. Lines 5 and 7 are 6 and 10 now.

Comment: Do you have `:locale` in your url? And please add the method, where you set your current locale.

Comment: Locale is in URL like this: http://localhost:3000/de/devices/3/events
Updated question.

Comment: Ok, if I remove all add_breadcrumbs calls before line 10, it doesn't work at line 10. So add_breadcrumbs seems to trigger locale detection somehow.

Comment: Thanks! before_filter was the solution! :)